# SonataAdmin, add a page in the dashboard

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm working on Symfony2 and SonataAdminBundle.

I need to add a module in my admin for send email to all users.

So, i need a new page with a link in the menu.. How can i do that simply ?

Fow now i have my blocks in my dashboard, so one one page..

Comment: Can you elaborate it with more brief